# Enforce unique constraint without denormalization

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, constraint, unique-constraint

## Option 1

I have a database schema that looks something like this:
https://dbfiddle.uk/JKCTjadD
[image]

1. A `Task` belongs to a `Service` (like in [ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html))
2. A `Task` can be reassigned to another `Service`.
3. `TaskConfig` tracks the reassignment history (and other configs), and the latest record (using `inserted_on DESC`) is the `Service` that a `Task` is currently assigned to.
4. A `Service` has a unique constraint (`service_name`, `environment`). Environment has its own table but illustrated here as an Enum for brevity.
5. A `Task` also has a unique constraint (`task_name`, `environment`).

##### The Problem

The `environment` in `Task` is duplicated/redundant: the `Service` associated with the `Task` already has the `environment` that the `Task` is in.

## Option 2

I decided to move `Service_id` from `TaskConfig` into `Task`:
https://dbfiddle.uk/QB7k9hK3
[image]
I can then use the following query to fetch the latest pairs of (`task_name`, `environment_name`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (task_name, environment_name) * 
FROM TaskConfig 
JOIN Task ON Task.id = Task_id
JOIN Service ON Service.id = Service_id
ORDER BY task_name, environment_name, inserted_on DESC
```

##### The problem

1. I can no longer have a unique constraint on (`task_name`, `environment`) since `environment` is not in the `Task` table.
2. A future developer could mistakenly select (`task_name`,
   `Service_id`) which will not result in unique (`task_name`,
   `environment`) pairs.

## Help

How would you propose to resolve the issues above?
If there are no better ways, which of the 2 options above is the better schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a task can belong only to one service, the second data model is the correct one. To enforce your constraint, you have to add a redundant copy of `environment` to `task`:

- add a new column `environment` to `task` and fill it with the values from `service`
- add a redundant unique constraint on `service (id, environment)`
- define the foreign key from `task` to `service` using these two columns

Now you can add your constraint. Yes, this answer needs a redundant copy of `environment`, but there is no way to avoid that.